# AngularJs: ngClass with multiple statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I need to add two classes through one `ng-class` definition

One looks like

```
{true: 'bar', false: ''}[someVar === 'bar']
```

And the other looks like

```
{foo: someOtherVar === 'foo'}
```

If I join them

```
<div ng-class="{true: 'bar', false: ''}[someVar === 'bar'],{foo: someOtherVar === 'foo'}">
```

it doesn't work. What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can do it like this:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'bar' : someVar === 'bar', 'foo' : someOtherVar === 'bar' }"></div>
```

Just for brevity you could also do this if you need to add two claases and are checking just one variable.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'bar foo' : expression1 }"></div>
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer because you were first :) thnx!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a css class in quotes first, and then a statement that evaluates to true or false after.

For example:

```
<div ng-class="{'bar':someVar==='bar', 'foo':someOtherVar ==='foo'}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-class="{'bar': someVar === 'bar', 'foo': someOtherVar === 'foo'}">
```

Hope, it will help.